# Como Escolher posição para imprimir um string em um texto?

Tags: ios, string, objective-c

Estou desenvolvendo um app onde o usuário pode escolher em meio a um texto, a posição onde deve ser impresso o valor de saída de uma string.
 Exemplo:
 Normlamente quando vamos imprimir uma string em meio a um texto fazemos assim:

```
 NSLog (@" Um texto com:%@", minhaVariavelString);
```

Ou quando usamos um UITextField:

```
_meuTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Meu valor:%@.", minhaString];
```

Mantendo a posição de `%@` fixa.

Porm quero poder fornecer ao user a possibilidade de alterar a posição de saída da string em uma tela de composição de texto quando o app estiver sendo executado.

Answer (score 2):

Basta criar uma `NSMutableString` e usar o método `insertString:AtIndex:`.

Exemplo:

```
NSMutableString *vitima = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Minha String Legal"];
NSLog(@"%@", vitima); //Imprime "Minha String Legal"
[vitima insertString:@"Não tão " atIndex:13];
NSLog(@"%@", vitima); //Imprime "Minha String Não tão Legal"
```

Comment: Blz! Meio caminho andado, agora vou fazer isso na View, vou ver se consigo fazer de um modo Drag and Drop! Vlw!